# SQL Server XQuery returns an error

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I am performing a query against an XML data type column in SQL Server 2012. An example of the data is:

```
<ns:Resume xmlns:ns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume">
  <ns:Name>
    <ns:Name.Prefix></ns:Name.Prefix>
    <ns:Name.First>Shai</ns:Name.First>
    <ns:Name.Middle></ns:Name.Middle>
    <ns:Name.Last>Bassli</ns:Name.Last>
    <ns:Name.Suffix></ns:Name.Suffix>
  </ns:Name>
  ...
</ns:Resume>
```

I am trying to write a query to return the first names.

This query returns a list of first names as expected:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume' AS ns)
SELECT [Resume].query('(//ns:Name.First)').value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM   HumanResources.JobCandidate;
```

However, this query returns an error:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume' AS ns)
SELECT [Resume].value('(//ns:Name.First)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM   HumanResources.JobCandidate;
```

Error:

> Msg 9314, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   XQuery [HumanResources.JobCandidate.Resume.value()]: Cannot implicitly atomize or apply 'fn:data()' to complex content elements, found type 'xs:anyType' within inferred type '(element(ns{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:Name.First,xs:string) | element(ns{http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume}:Name.First,xs:anyType)) ?'.

There's some basic understanding that I'm missing here but I'm not sure what it is. Can someone enlighten me? Why does the second query return an error?

Answer (score 1):

Your XPath expression could lead to multiple rows being returned, for each row in the SQL Server table. You'll need to use a `CROSS APPLY` and a call to `.nodes()` to get that information you're after:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume' AS ns)
SELECT 
    JobCandidateID,
    ResNames.value('(ns:Name.First)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM   
    HumanResources.JobCandidate
CROSS APPLY
    [Resume].nodes('/ns:Resume/ns:Name') AS XTbl(ResNames)
```

That should return all `JobCandidateID` values and all first names defined in the `Resume` XML column for each row in the table.

If you can be sure that there's only ever going to be a single `<name>` tag in your XML column, then you could also shorten this to:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/07/adventure-works/Resume' AS ns)
SELECT 
    JobCandidateID,
    [Resume].value('(/ns:Resume/ns:Name/ns:Name.First)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM   
    HumanResources.JobCandidate
```

Comment: I am sure that you are correct marc_s, but things like this in XML always throw me for a loop.  Can you explain why the `'..[1]'` already present doesn't address the problem of possibly returning more than one item per row?  thnx..

Comment: @RBarryYoung: yes, I thought that `[1]` would do the trick, too! But it appears (from the error message thrown) that by searching for `//ns:Name.First` somehow the XQuery processing in SQL Server assumes there's a `Name.First,xs:string` and a second `Name.First,xs:any` in the XML schema collection (again: I'm not sure why that happens - I've just seen it happen on occasion). In that case, the XQuery processor cannot figure out what the `Name.First` element is (what type) and thus barfs up

Comment: So using `'(/ns:Resume/ns:Name/ns:Name.First)[1]'` instead of `'(//ns:Name.First)[1]'` makes the difference? Why?

Comment: @Seiker: because you're **more explicit** about what you want - you're not asking for *any `<name>` anywhere in the whole XML document* - you're asking for a very specific, very clearly defined value

Comment: *sigh* every time I think I have SQL server XQuery figured out, I don't.  :-(

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the examples posted, I also have a number of examples that work including one that uses `CROSS APPLY`. Sorry to go on but as stated in the original question, I just wanted to understand _why_ the error was thrown. I understand that the rooted XPath selector is more specific and will match the same number or fewer nodes than the non-rooted version. However, it is also capable of returning more than one result so I don't get why the [1] isn't just as good in both cases.